# Azure CLI Get Current Service Principal Details in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I have Azure Pipeline setup with Azure CLI task 
I am using Service Connection. In az cli task I want to retrieve current Service Connection details (like appId name objectId etc..) which I am using to run this task.

`az ad sp show` required id parameter, which will not work in my case. I want to know that id dynamically

Is there any way to get current SP details?

[image: Azure Pipeline]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now use a checkbox to expose the service principal id, secret and tenant in the Azure CLI script.

[image: Checkbox to allow service principal details in script]

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this same issue, and found out the simplest possible way to get the SP Id in Azure Cli task in the pipeline:

First, define in the task addSpnToEnvironment like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
```

After that, you can get the SP Id from $env:servicePrincipalId and use it like this:

```
az deployment group create ... --parameters SPId=$env:servicePrincipalId
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get your current session context with

```
az account show
```

and then simply get some extra details on the service principal

```
az ad sp show --id <guid>
```

and application

```
az ad app show --id <guid>
```

Comment: I want to know sp id for running a pipeline task dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I found Service principle is in Azure Active Directory. And i cannot add them to azure devops service connection. What i can add is `Azure subscription` or `azure resource group`.
Not sure show how did you add your applications to azure service connection.

If you want to get the connection details. You can try `az accout show` for **azure subscription**, or `az group show --name` for **azure resource group**

Answer (score -1):

Combine with Adam Marczak's solution with python in one liner,

```
az ad sp show --id $(az account show| python -c 'import json,sys;print json.load(sys.stdin)["user"]["name"]')
```

Comment: you can have the second part much easier by using --query ;) `az account show --query "user.name" -o tsv`