# How to programmatically get current Azure Devops pipeline object ID in order to grant access for Azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I have the following task which works - I then use the variable value to pass as a parameter to a bicep file which provisions an Azure Key Vault, where the pipeline has access to it's secrets.

```
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Set Object ID Variable'
      name: PrincipalObject
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'service-connection-name'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          objectId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "<service-connection-display-name>" --query [].id --output tsv)
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pipelineObjectId;]$objectId"
```

However, it would be better if I didn't have to manually lookup the service connection principal in Azure AD to get the display name and paste it into the YAML.

Is there is a way of programmatically getting the currently executing object ID? That way the task becomes re-usable.

Comment: Unfortunately Azure Active Directory is not supported at this time as a Bicep functionality. Out of curiosity why do you need the object ID of Service Principle executing the Bicep?

Comment: The pipeline uses bicep to provision infrastructure including SQL databases, and puts the connection strings into key vault secrets. The pipeline then needs to read these connection string secrets in order to run schema updates for the application when being deployed.

Comment: @DreadedFrost I'm not sure my question is related to Bicep itself though? I am trying to obtain the DevOps service connection object ID which I pass to Bicep file in a later task...

Comment: I was just wondering why you need the object ID at all as part of your bicep deployment. The Pipeline should execute/authenticate as the service principle using RBAC. I am guessing it's writing to a shared key vault the service principle may not have access to?

Comment: The Azure Pipeline won't be able to read the secrets of the Azure KeyVault unless I explicitly add an access policy to the KeyVault allowing the pipeline read access to the secrets. I'm doing this in the bicep file by defining the access policies with the key vault definition.

Answer (score 0):

Its not directly possible to retrieve the Azure DevOps service connection ID, But You can refer the [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031598/azure-cli-get-current-service-principal-details-in-azure-pipeline) answers By BennyM, Adam Marczak and Jani and [SO Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249734/how-to-get-objectid-for-the-current-azure-devops-pipeline-service-principle) answer to retrieve the object ID of Service connection running the Pipeline.

*Use AzureCLI@2 task and check-mark Access service principal details in script:-*

[image]

*You can also add addSpnToEnvironment: true flag to true in your script*

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
 

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az account show
        az ad sp show --id xxxxxxxf62 
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Also, While running the pipeline make sure you check Enable system diagnostics and run your pipeline to get additional information on your Service connection.

[image]